# O que é necessário para ganhar o chapéu "Hero Of Time"?

Tags: suporte, winterbash-2017

Eu fiz a pergunta [Existe alguma maneira pythônico de fazer "slice" de um array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/265066/3635) exatamente as 19:00:07 (UTC), no entanto já ganhei outro chapéu neste meio tempo mas o "Hero Of Time" não apareceu pra mim.

A descrição diz:

> ask a question when it is 7:00 pm in any time zone

Se entendi corretamente, isto de qualquer timezone se a UTC, ou estou enganado, na verdade eu deveria usar a minha timezone local e perguntar neste momento?

Uma nota importante, eu sou de São Paulo, logo estou no horário de verão, o qual adianta uma hora, então atualmente estou em -2:00 em comparação ao UTC.

Se o procedimento foi correto, é necessário algo a mais, como talvez ganhar upvote na pergunta feita as 7:00pm?

Comment: Precisa não, o chápeu tem um delay para aparecer mesmo, eu ganhei ele após fazer [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264635/por-que-tipos-primitivos-com-ponto-flutuante-divididos-ou-multiplicados-por-dete), mas não foi de imediato.

Comment: @Articuno eu acho que talvez seja o upvote um fator necessário.

Comment: Acho que não, pois fui conferir meu historico e o primeiro voto que recebi(apesar de terem sido 2 negativos ¬¬') foram quase 1 hora depois.

Comment: @Articuno eu só ganhei o chapéu após postar no Meta essa pergunta, a 21:00 UTC (19:00 em São Paulo) e quase ao mesmo tempo recebi um upvote na pergunta no site principal, algo de errado não esta certo :P

Comment: Mas é em qualquer timezone, foi uma mera coincidência ser o de Brasilia :p , o meu mesmo foi UTC, como da sua pergunta linkada